# how to define style rules on server side either in json or php for android app

Tags: php, android, json

I have an app that have style.xml in which I define style for button. I want to remove the style.xml and define it on server side in the form of rules
 e.g 
<`condition`> {`vision` : `low`}
<`action`> {`textSize` : `25sp`}
either using json or php. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking just to render php server side a variable that might be in a json object?

Comment: I want to define the style attributes in json and the android app should implement that rules

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [ask].

Comment: Why not just include the json file(s) with the various parameters/conditions in the assets or res>raw folder? From there you can process the json data based on specific conditions and return the values for that condition as int for width, height, text size, text color, text string, etc..

Answer (score 0):

This working example assumes that you've put your json file in the assets folder.

I created a custom Button class that will pull the various parameters from the json file based on the condition request. Each object in a json array is indexed from 0 - the last object. Using that format, you can call the needed object based on its index. For this example, I called index 0 which is the first object in the array.

**ConditionalButton Class**

```
    public class ConditionalButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public int txtColor;
    public float txtSize;
    public int choice;

    public ConditionalButton(Context context, int cond) {
        super(context);
        choice = cond;
        setCondition(cond);
    }

    public ConditionalButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCondition(choice);
    }

    public void setCondition(int condition){
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
            JSONArray jsArry = obj.getJSONArray("conditions");

            JSONObject jsCond = jsArry.getJSONObject(condition);
            Log.d("Details-->", jsCond.toString());
            String textSize_value = jsCond.getString("condition_size");
            String textColor_value = jsCond.getString("condition_color");
            String width_value = jsCond.getString("condition_width");
            String height_value = jsCond.getString("condition_height");

            txtColor = Integer.valueOf(textColor_value);
            txtSize = Float.valueOf(textSize_value);
            int w = Integer.valueOf(width_value);
            int h = Integer.valueOf(height_value);

            textColor(txtColor);
            textSize(txtSize);
            setLayoutParams(h,w);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("style.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

    public void textColor(int color) {
        this.setTextColor(color);
    }

    public void textSize(float size) {
        this.setTextSize(size);
    }

    public void setLayoutParams(int height, int width){
        this.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
    }

}
```

Then you can include the view in your layout like any other view. In your activity class, you would call this to get it to work.

```
    ConditionalButton test = new ConditionalButton(this, 0);
    test.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    //0 is the first index in the array of objects
```

In your custom Button class you can set whatever parameters you need to based on your requirements. If you choose to retrieve the json from a server, I suppose you could use Volley. Haven't tried that yet.

Here's the json file I used:

```
    {
  "conditions": [
    {
      "condition_name": "one",
      "condition_size": "18",
      "condition_width": "128",
      "condition_height": "72",
      "condition_color": "-16776961"
    },
    {
      "condition_name": "two",
      "condition_size": "26",
      "condition_width": "256",
      "condition_height": "92",
      "condition_color": "-16777931"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note: Color integers have to be in the format in the example shown otherwise they won't work.

I hope this helps. You could alter the json and custom button class to set the style for any parameter required for the view.

Comment: Dear Steve C. I am planning to define rules on server side so that I am able to change or add new rules in future easily.................Thanks for your kind response.....please try if this is possible

Comment: @Anees I'm sorry but I don't have time to work out all the bugs. I have created a project and there are two options, load from server or load from assets folder. You can initialize either one. Network method retrieves the json data but doesn't set it for some reason. I'm too tired to figure it out. I uploaded the project to GitHub [here](https://github.com/power7714/JSONStyleTest). Feel free to play around with it. If you manage to get it working the way you want, please submit a pull request to merge the project so others can see it as well in the future.